# Load Xml File Throws Exception HRESULT: 0xC00CE584

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to load an XML file from Steam but it throws me this exception HRESULT: 0xC00CE584.
Loading other xml files from localhost and other website is working.
I also tried to set all XMLSettings to true but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
Uri steamUriTemp = new Uri("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=xml");
var steamXML = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(steamUriTemp);
```

This is the XML file I'm trying to load: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=xml

Is something wrong with this xml file ? Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing an XmlLoadSettings object with the ProhibitDTD property set to false like this:

```
var steamXML = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(steamUriTemp, new XmlLoadSettings{ProhibitDTD = False});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this error is having an invalid character in the file.  Something like an & or <.  These are XML special characters and will cause violations when used as data instead of indicators.

The file you are attempting to load has some HTML markup in it that is most likely the cause of this issue.  Specifically the Contents element for Team Fortress 2.  I think if you remove the reserved characters this file will load normally like the other file you tested.